# cuda: Any efficient way to get non-zero elements in sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, cuda

I have a big 2D histogram, in which most of the elements are zero. I want to put the non-zero ones and their positions to 2 arrays(or vectors). Is there any efficient way to do this?

I hope have stated my problem clearly. Here is some detail.

1) I have a 1024*1024 histogram, and filled by atomicAdd().
2) For each element in histogram, if it's not a local peak, it's content is set to be 0. (Usually I have <50 peaks) In this way, my histogram becomes a big sparse matrix.
3) My problem is : I want to put all non-zero elements and their positions to 2 arrays. I don't know how to do it efficiently.

Hope for your suggestions, thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use a prefix sum (scan) or thrust's [`for_each`](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/arbitrary_transformation.cu) for that.

Comment: It does strike me odd that I can't seem to find a dense-to-sparse vector conversion primitive in cuSPARSE.

Comment: @Domi - how about this and related functions? http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-dense2csr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrust [histogram example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/histogram.cu) should give you some ideas.

The terminology can be confusing: a "dense histogram" as described there contains all bins, whether zero or not (equivalent to your sparse matrix).  A "sparse histogram" contains only the non-zero bins, equivalent to your desired result.

That example actually generates the histogram -- either dense or sparse.  So you may wish to use that method directly, instead of whatever method you are using to do the histogramming (AtomicAdd, while functional, may be slower.)

Or if you prefer, the comments in that code give a description for how to convert "dense" to "sparse" and vice-versa.  To create a sparse histogram (which is what you want) thrust [copy_if](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html) is suggested.

Since you want both the histogram bin and it's index, you could do something like the following:

1. create a vector as long as your histogram vector, and sequence it (`thrust::sequence`) to create the indices.
2. create a zip iterator to combine each histogram bin and it's corresponding index into a single tuple.
3. use copy_if to select the tuples whose bin values are non-zero.